# Hide element for mobile only - Semantic UI

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I have problem with hiding image for mobile devices. I'm using Semantic UI framework. In documentation I found some classes:

1. mobile only - will only display below 768px
2. tablet only - will only display between 768px - 991px
3. computer only - will always display 992px and above

Just for example, I'm using "computer only" classes to hide image on tablets and mobile, but the result confused me.

```
<div class="ui grid stackable">
  <div class="row middle aligned">
    <div class="nine wide column">
      <h1 class="ui header blue">Default Header.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="seven wide computer only column">
      <img class="ui image" src="http://icons.veryicon.com/png/System/iNiZe/niZe%20%20%20IMG.png" alt="" title="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3xkrx/318/

Comment: Could you clarify the question, please? What about the result confused you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Also, I found one more solution. May be for someone it will helpful.

I've added classes `"mobile hidden"` to column which I wanted to hide on mobile devices.

```
<div class="ui grid stackable">
 <div class="row middle aligned">
  <div class="nine wide column">
   <h1 class="ui header blue">Default Header.</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="seven wide column mobile hidden">
    <img class="ui image" src="http://icons.veryicon.com/png/System/iNiZe/niZe%20%20%20IMG.png" alt="" title="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Add `mobile only grid` to `img` tag

The correct expression is below:

```
<img class="ui image mobile only grid " src="http://icons.veryicon.com/png/System/iNiZe/niZe%20%20%20IMG.png" alt="" title="">
```

Comment: thanks, it works fine in jsfiddle, but don't work on my website. Image on widescreen just disappear, something magical happens. I used
class="ui image computer only grid "

Comment: this is not going to work supposedly, because it will show on tablet

Answer (score 7):

Visit here works really well

```
/* Mobile */

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  [class*="mobile hidden"],
  [class*="tablet only"]:not(.mobile),
  [class*="computer only"]:not(.mobile),
  [class*="large monitor only"]:not(.mobile),
  [class*="widescreen monitor only"]:not(.mobile),
  [class*="or lower hidden"] {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
etc...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8LkLoxcx/