# How do I hide and show elements based on device, screen size in Semantic UI?

Tags: semantic-ui

I've brushed the documentation and couldn't find it. Does Semantic UI have the same system of Bootstrap 4 of using classes to hide show elements based on screen size? Can someone give some direction?

the closest I got was this link

https://semantic-ui.com/elements/container.html

It gives no instruction on how to use it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183708/hide-element-for-mobile-only-semantic-ui

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683705/semantic-ui-how-to-hide-element-on-mobile-only

Comment: One more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172155/which-one-is-the-right-one-semantic-ui-responsive-visibility